# Im not using Map function here but its throwing an error that i'm using map in groovy

Tags: groovy

Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.LinkedHashMap.reset() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: keySet(), keySet(), keySet(), get(java.lang.Object), get(java.lang.Object), get(java.lang.Object)
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.LinkedHashMap.reset() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: keySet(), keySet(), keySet(), get(java.lang.Object), get(java.lang.Object), get(java.lang.Object)
at main.run(main.groovy:394)

Comment: What code produces such error? Provide [mcve] please.

Comment: And, BTW, error is saying that you are trying to use `reset` function on map object.

Answer (score 0):

There is code at line 394 of `main.groovy` that is calling `reset()` (directly or indirectly) on an instance of `LinkedHashMap`.  That isn't valid.